# What is the difference between fit() and fit_predict() in SpectralClustering

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I am trying to understand and use the [spectral clustering](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering.html#sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering.fit_predict) from [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.cluster).
Let us say we have X matrix input and we create a spectral clustering object as follows:

```
clustering = SpectralClustering(n_clusters=2,
         assign_labels="discretize",
         random_state=0)
```

Then, we call a fit_predict using the spectral cluster object.

```
clusters =  clustering.fit_predict(X)
```

What confuses me is that when does 'the affinity matrix for X using the selected affinity is created'? Because as per the documentation the 
*fit_predict()* method  'Performs clustering on X and returns cluster labels.' But it doesn't explicitly say that it also computes 'the affinity matrix for X using the selected affinity' before clustering.

I appreciate any help or tips.

Comment: **Use the source, Luke!** It's very easy to check what thd `fit_predict` method does...

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I don't think the question deserves negative score.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already implied in another answer, `fit_predict` is just a convenience method in order to return the cluster labels. According to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering.html#sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering.fit), `fit`

> Creates an affinity matrix for X using the selected affinity, then applies spectral clustering to this affinity matrix.

while `fit_predict`

> Performs clustering on X and returns cluster labels.

Here, *Performs clustering on X* should be understood as what is described for `fit`, i.e. *Creates an affinity matrix [...]*.

It is not difficult to verify that calling `fit_predict` is equivalent to getting the `labels_` attribute from the object after `fit`; using some dummy data, we have

```
from sklearn.cluster import SpectralClustering
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [10, 0],
               [10, 2], [10, 4], [1, 0]])

# 1st way - use fit and get the labels_
clustering = SpectralClustering(n_clusters=2,
     assign_labels="discretize",
     random_state=0)

clustering.fit(X)
clustering.labels_
# array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1])

# 2nd way - using fit_predict
clustering2 = SpectralClustering(n_clusters=2,
     assign_labels="discretize",
     random_state=0)

clustering2.fit_predict(X)
# array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1])

np.array_equal(clustering.labels_, clustering2.fit_predict(X))
# True
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7813f7efb/sklearn/base.py#L429) of `fit_predict()` it seems that it's just a convenience method - it literally just calls `fit()` and returns labels from the object.